# Changing UILabel's text color while user typing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UILabel` that displays the char count of a `UITextfield`. It works, but I can't change the the label's text color when `x` is less than zero. Actually I don't have idea where is the answer, because I can log/display the proper data, only the color doesn't changes at `-1,-2..`.

```
- (void)updateLabelUsingContentsOfTextField:(id)sender {

    NSString *numberPlaceholder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ((UITextField *)sender).text];

    int x = 43-[numberPlaceholder length];

    if (x <= 0) {

        self.charNumbers.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        NSLog(@"IF DEV LOG 1 - INTEGER IS %d", x);

    }

    self.charNumbers.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];

    NSLog(@"X INTEGER IS %d", x);

    if (x <= 43) {

        self.charNumbers.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
           NSLog(@"IF DEV LOG 2 - INTEGER IS %d", x);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[numberPlaceholder length]` returns an unsigned integer so the incorrect comparison is probably the result of an underflow. Try casting `[numberPlaceholder length]` as an int so the values are of the same type:

```
int x = 43 - (int)[numberPlaceholder length];
```